# Get all values from jtextfield in jpanel

Tags: java, swing, components

I can values all jtextfield in jpanel. but values are disordered. How i get order by jtextfield position.

I use follow sample code:

```
private void all(Container container) {
    for (Component c : container.getComponents()) {
        if (c instanceof JTextField) {
            data.add(((JTextField)c).getText());
            System.out.println(i+" = "+((JTextField)c).getText());
        } 
        else if (c instanceof JComboBox)
        {
            System.out.println(i+" = "+((JComboBox)c).getSelectedItem());
        }
        else if (c instanceof JFormattedTextField)
        {
            data.add(i+" ni "+((JFormattedTextField)c).getText());

        }
        else if (c instanceof Container) {
           all((Container)c);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Place them in some kind of `List` in the order you want.  The `Component` order is not an appropriate condition to use as components may be laid out in a different order that they added...

Comment: Thank's for answer. So how i do it by another way.

Comment: Unless you have access to the fields, you can't really

Comment: Or else you can use different variables for each component, like `i for JTextField, j for JComboBox and k for JFormattedTextField`, that way you can have a sequential order of values, if I understood what you asking correctly.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I have little english. But you right understood. I will try

Comment: I solved this problem by the following method. I used jLayeredPanel instead of jPanel as main container.